# % _ in search form displays all results

Tags: php, mysql, character, wildcard

if the search form is blank, it should display an error that something should be entered by the user. it should only show those results which contain the keywords the user has entered in the search textbox.

however, if the user enters % or _ or +, it displays all results. how do i display an error when the user enters these wildcard characters?

my search php code:

```
$search_result = "";

$search_result = $_GET["q"];

$search_result = trim($search_result);

if ($search_result == "") {
  echo  "<p>Search Error</p><p>Please enter a search...</p>" ;
  exit();
      }

$result = mysql_query('SELECT cQuotes, vAuthor, cArabic, vReference FROM thquotes WHERE cQuotes LIKE "%' .  mysql_real_escape_string($search_result) .'%" ORDER BY idQuotes DESC', $conn)
  or die ('Error: '.mysql_error());

// there's either one or zero records. Again, no need for a while loop
function h($s) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES);
} 


?>

<div class="caption">Search Results</div>
<div class="center_div">
<table>
    <?php while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right; font-size:15px;"><?php h($row['cArabic']); ?></td>
            <td style="font-size:16px;"><?php h($cQuotes); ?></td>
            <td style="font-size:12px;"><?php h($row['vAuthor']); ?></td>
            <td style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic; text-align:right;"><?php h($row['vReference']); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<?php

?>
</div>
```

Comment: use preg_replace on your $search_result - replacing any wildcard chars to nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to wipe out special characters

you can check [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or [preg_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) (Whatever method suits you) for this.

like: $search_result=preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $search_result);

Comment: thanks for that. it works. but what if an apostrophe is required in the query? just a single apostrophe shouldn't display all the results but how would i allow it using regex?

Comment: You can add as many special character in you regex, like ' doesn't have special meaning so you can add it directly, but for some u may need \(for escaping)     like : "/^[a-zA-Z0-9,'.\-\s]*$/"

Answer (score 1):

Check for that special case $_GET[q] = "%" in your code, just like how you're checking for a blank query. Or, strip out all occurrences of % and _ in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$search_result = preg_replace ('/[%_*]/', '' , $_GET["q"] );
```

Try it. I haven't got the tools to check that regex specifically. But this is the direction of which would probably work for you.

Then your result will be safer and cleaner, and if a user typed "%" you would have an empty search.

Comment: it works. but what if an apostrophe is required in the query? just a single apostrophe shouldn't display all the results but how would i allow it using regex?

Comment: @nik has answered the question for you in his comments.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solution without regex's that replaces all occurences of your special characters.

```
$search_result = "";
$special_cases = array( '%', '_', '+' );
$search_result = str_replace( $special_cases, '',  $_GET["q"] );
```

Comment: tried it. doesn't work. it's showing search error even if a proper keyword is entered

Comment: for % and _, it works but for + sign it still displays all results.